# Microsoft CRM 365 upload files to Opportunity

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-sdk

Using Microsoft.Xrm SDK I have a requirement to upload documents to Files section of Opportunity in Microsoft CRM 365:

[image: Opportunity Files]

I understand that Files refer to entity SharepointDocumentLocation and I can read/create records in this entity but I am unable to figrue outt how to upload actual file and then show a link to file in my application.

Could you please refer me to some documentation/code sample explaining how to upload documents to files?

Thanks in anticipation!

Comment: File should be uploaded directly inside sharepoint, so you don't need to use the Xrm SDK, inside sharepoint you will find a folder for each Opportunity record where the Files were listed/requested from Dynamics.

Comment: thanks @GuidoPreite. Could you please point me to some document which explains CRM's SharepointDocumentLocation entity and its link with files in sharepoint.

Comment: you can't upload files using the Xrm SDK, you need sharepoint one, so knowing how SharepointDocumentLocation entity is structured is kind of useless. In your case the Opportunity has an ID and a name, if you open the sharepoint configured with that Dynamics instance you will find there a folder with that ID (and the name if I remember correctly) from the opportunity. If you upload a file from sharepoint it will appear inside Dynamics. Here you can find a c# example but I never tested it http://informaquest.com/index.php/2015/11/20/uploading-files-directly-to-sharepoint-and-link-in-crm/

Comment: @GuidoPreite thanks for your reply and the link. I am going through the code in the article but I think a lot has changed since 2015 so I am changing it for the latest SDK. UploadFileToSP function is thowing exception "File Not Found." at ctx.ExecuteQuery();. Can you look at the method and see what is the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @GuidoPreite i have sorted it out. Please add your last comment as a reply and I will select it as an answer. thanks for your help!

Comment: you can write the answer and add the code you wrote or the changes you made to make it work or the explanation of the steps you did